# How to exclude Administrators from being filtered in wordpress Gravity Views Advanced Filtering Extension?

Tags: wordpress, filtering, gravity-forms-plugin

I've got Advanced Filtering Extension from github:
https://github.com/tinbot-development/ciew-advanced-filter

I'm using filtering to show submitted entries only to who created them,
but then admin can't view other entries than his own.
I want admin to view everything, not only his own entries.
Could anyone tell me what code im supposed to add to this plugin to enable admins view everything?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can exclude Administrators from being filtered.
Just select the option: "Logged-in User (disabled for Admins)".

It is explained here at the bottom of the page.
https://docs.gravityview.co/article/203-how-to-show-only-results-submitted-by-the-current-user